# active record - destroy_all and create inside a transaction

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, transactions

Below is the code we execute on mysql 5.5 using rails 3.1.6

```
Model.transaction do
  model.events.destroy_all
  2.times { model.events.create!(some_body) }
end
```

The expectation is to always have two and only two event objects under the model.

When I run this code on two threads, I often end up with four event objects. I was hoping that both the threads would serialize the execution of code inside the transaction block. Apparently transactions do not work that way.

Is there a common pattern to do this kind of thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use [pessimistic locking](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html) to lock your model before deleting and creating the events.